# How to get the count/records from the table which is not there in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the employee number who don't have outpunch record for the given date.

For example, In the below table, an employee with number  9100001820 don't have any record with MODE ='OUT' So Query should give his employee number as output

```
Employee_Number  PDate          PTime          MODE
9100001820  9/8/2019    15:03:29    IN
9100001820  9/8/2019    14:55:34    IN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select e.employee_number
from employees e  -- certainly you have such a table with all employees
where not exists (select 1
                  from punches p
                  where p.employee_number = e.employee_number and
                        p.mode = 'OUT' and p.pdate = '2019-08-09'
                 );
```

Actually, though, I suspect you want employees who punched in on the date but didn't punch out.  Use aggregation for that:

```
select p.employee_number
from punches p
where p.pdate = '2019-08-09'
group by p.employee_number
having sum(case when p.mode = 'OUT' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Yup, you are right!..Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns all the employee_numbers where there is no 'OUT' mode inserted.

```
select t1.Employee_Number 
from yourtable t1
left outer join yourtable t2 on t2.Employee_Number = t1.Employee_Number and t2.Mode='Out'
where t2.Employee_Number is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select t1.Employee_Number
from yourtable t1
where not exists (select * from yourtable where Employee_Number = t1.Employee_Number and Mode='Out')
```

Comment: Yes! Your code works for my requirements. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want employees who have punched in, but not punched out. In other words their latest punch record is a punch in record.

```
select *
from (select employee_number
            ,pdate
            ,ptime
            ,mode
            ,max(pdate) over (partition by employee_number)        as max_pdate
            ,max(ptime) over (partition by employee_number, pdate) as max_ptime
        from employee_punch
        where pdate = '2019-08-09'
) m
where pdate = max_pdate
and ptime = max_ptime
and mode = 'IN'
```

Note, if you have shifts that span midnight, you will need to be smarter about your day filter.
Also, in Gordon's example, he uses not exists. That is rarely performant because on most optimizers it forces an inefficient nested loop join. Eray, gave the outer join example, almost always the better way to go.
My example is a more flexible version of Gordon's summary code, either of which are probably closer to what you want and equally performant.